# XSLT Get first date out of xml rules

Tags: xml, xslt

How can i get the first date out of multiple lines?
So i get a XML with orderlines, but in the header i want the first requested date.
I try to explain with some code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xmlOrders>
  <rec>
    <supplierCode></supplierCode>
    <orderNumber>abcd</orderNumber>
    <xmlOrderLines>
      <rec>
        <orderLine>10</orderLine>
        <requestedDeliveryDate>20200707</requestedDeliveryDate>
      </rec>
      <rec>
        <orderLine>20</orderLine>
        <requestedDeliveryDate>20200916</requestedDeliveryDate>
      </rec>
      <rec>
        <orderLine>30</orderLine>
        <requestedDeliveryDate>20200601</requestedDeliveryDate>
      </rec>
    </xmlOrderLines>
  </rec>
</xmlOrders>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<DataSet>
    <vorh>
    <vorh.vorh_dat_gewenst>FIRST DATE OF ORDERLINES HERE.....</vorh.vorh_dat_gewenst>
        <xsl:for-each select="xmlOrders/rec/xmlOrderLines/rec">
        <vorr>
        <vorr.vorr_volgorde><xsl:value-of select="orderLine"/></vorr.vorr_volgorde>
        <vorr.vorr_dat_gewenst><xsl:value-of select="requestedDeliveryDate"/></vorr.vorr_dat_gewenst>
        </vorr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </vorh>
</DataSet>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are limited to XSLT 1.0 you need to use a rather primitive method:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/xmlOrders">
    <DataSet>
        <vorh>
            <vorh.vorh_dat_gewenst>
                <xsl:for-each select="rec/xmlOrderLines/rec">
                    <xsl:sort select="requestedDeliveryDate" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="requestedDeliveryDate"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </vorh.vorh_dat_gewenst>
            <xsl:for-each select="rec/xmlOrderLines/rec">
                <vorr>
                    <vorr.vorr_volgorde>
                        <xsl:value-of select="orderLine"/>
                    </vorr.vorr_volgorde>
                    <vorr.vorr_dat_gewenst>
                        <xsl:value-of select="requestedDeliveryDate"/>
                    </vorr.vorr_dat_gewenst>
                </vorr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </vorh>
    </DataSet>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Unless your processor happens to support the EXSLT `math:min()` extension function. In such case you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
extension-element-prefixes="math">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/xmlOrders">
    <DataSet>
        <vorh>
            <vorh.vorh_dat_gewenst>
                <xsl:value-of select="math:min(rec/xmlOrderLines/rec/requestedDeliveryDate)"/>
            </vorh.vorh_dat_gewenst>
            <xsl:for-each select="rec/xmlOrderLines/rec">
                <vorr>
                    <vorr.vorr_volgorde>
                        <xsl:value-of select="orderLine"/>
                    </vorr.vorr_volgorde>
                    <vorr.vorr_dat_gewenst>
                        <xsl:value-of select="requestedDeliveryDate"/>
                    </vorr.vorr_dat_gewenst>
                </vorr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </vorh>
    </DataSet>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```